# React - how to make an export component private to its directory?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to limit the import of React components to it's own directory? So it is only possible to import inside the same directory?

For example I have the following dir strutcture:

```
src/
   apps/
      myapp.js
      /table
         table.js
         table-row.js
```

The file `table-row.js` has the following component

```
export const TableRow = ({row, index}) => {
    return <TableRow> ... </TableRow>
};
```

How to make `TableRow` private to `/table` dir, so I can not import outside this directory? But the `table/table.js` can import?

Comment: You can't do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only expose certain exports to files outside folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71865075/only-expose-certain-exports-to-files-outside-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant *actually* do this, but a pattern that I like to follow is to do something like

- src

  - components
  - MyComponent

    - MyComponent.jsx
    - PrivateHelperComponent.jsx
    - index.js

where the components resemble the follow:

```
//MyComponent.jsx
const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <PrivateHelperComponent />
    </div>
  )
>

export default MyComponent
```

```
//PrivateHelperComponent.jsx
const PrivateHelperComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  )
>

export default PrivateHelperComponent
```

```
//index.js
export { default } from "./MyComponent"
```

...Now the interface for importing from `<...>/components/MyComponent` is "clean", and you can only import the "default" component.

Of course, nothing stops you from doing `import PrivateHelperComponent from "<...>/components/MyComponent/PrivateHelperComponent"`, but at least in my opinion it clear what components are *meant* to be imported/reused and what aren't

Answer (score 1):

You can’t do that. But if you really want to make it private put table row (with no export) and table in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

There is no access modifier for exports in JS (all exports are accessible to all modules; aka public), so you cannot make an export private to its directory.